# Number of Characters representing a 160 bit ECC Public and private keys

Tags: cryptography

Can anyone "out" there help me to understand a number of characters representing public key and private key of a 160-bit Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC)? In my understanding, I expected such a key (eg public) to be expressed using 20 bytes, and when encoded in base64 and hexadecimal formats to be roughly 27 and 40 characters respectively. But to my surprise, the number of characters have been bigger than expected ones.

Do public and private keys have the same size in bits (and therefore characters)?

Some sources talked of compressed and uncompressed public keys without providing further details. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a hex dump of (a test version of) the public and private key? Does it start with hexadecimal `30`?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, though not answered my question fully. I ran an application that produced public and private keys using ECDH (secp160k1). In my understanding i expected the public key to have 20 bytes, and the exact number of characters representing it to vary depending on whether the key is encoded in hexadecimal or base64. Thank you for answers,but i need clear explanations on how these keys are represented.

Comment: By now the application produces public keys in base64 format.

Comment: The public key contains 86 characters and 2 equal signs (==) making a total of 88 characters. Is it the correct number of characters to represent a public key generated using a secp160k1 curve?

Comment: Does it start with the letter 'M'?

Comment: Yes both public and private keys start with letter M. What does it mean?

Comment: I hate these drive by anonymous users. Waste of time on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The private key is indeed 160-bit integer.
The public key is a point on the curve, usually represented by coordinates x and y, 160-bit each. So 320-bit total for the public key.

Comment: It's possible to use point compression to reduce public keys to 161 bits. But depending on the curve form you can run into patent trouble in the US if you do that.

Comment: That's the minimum, without point compression, but there are ASN.1 specifications out there, which may even include the domain parameters (which means at least 7 * key size + overhead).

Comment: Usually in ASN.1 parameters stored curve OID. Not all implementations even support specified by parameters curve.